# Java multithreading: cannot change thread priority

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads whose priority has been set using `setPriority()` function and still it shows same priority?

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class threadtest  extends Thread {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("running thread name is:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       System.out.println("running thread priority is:" + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        threadtest tt = new threadtest();
        tt.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
        threadtest tt1 = new threadtest();
        tt1.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
        tt1.run();
        tt.run();
    }
}
```

The output if the above code in my **ECLIPSE neon** is.

```
running thread name is:main
running thread priority is:5
running thread name is:main
running thread priority is:5
```

Even after having different priorities,it shows similar priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `Thread.start()`, not `Thread.run()`.

When you directly call the `run()` method than the code inside `run()` method will not be executed on a new thread, instead it will be executed on the same thread. On the other hand, when you call the `Thread.start()` method, then the code inside `run()` method will be executed on a new thread, which is actually created by the `start()` method:

```
public class threadtest extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running thread name is:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("running thread priority is:" + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        threadtest tt = new threadtest();
        tt.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
        threadtest tt1 = new threadtest();
        tt1.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
        tt1.start();
        tt.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:10
running thread priority is:1
```